# Creating a new array that counts the distance between specific numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, distance

This is easy to mis-explain so I'll simplify it. Let's say I have an array that are the results of dice throws. Like:

1 2 4 6 1 2 6 6 2 4 etc

Every time you throw a 6, you win. I want to create a new array which contains after how many turns you would win based on the original array. So the above array would create an array that is:

4 3 1

(it takes 4 turns to win, then 3, then 1)

So I only want to count the distance between the 6's. (I could also convert the dice results to binary win/lose)

How do I do this in excel? (or javascript, but really prefer excel)

Comment: I must remark that the array is over 100,000 items so I can't put it into javascript manually. I also need some way to save the array (which is why I prefer excel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Helper Column (Column A of Excel). Put 1 in the first cell (A2) of Helper column. Follow it up with the formula (in A3) =IF(B3=6,A2+1,A2).Drag it to the last row of to the given array.

Then Create a Result column (Column C of Excel). Type in formula (in C2)
=IF(ROW()-1=MAX(A:A),"",IF(IF(ROW()-1=1,COUNTIF(A:A,ROW()-1)+1,COUNTIF(A:A,ROW()-1))=0,"",IF(ROW()-1=1,COUNTIF(A:A,ROW()-1)+1,COUNTIF(A:A,ROW()-1))))

in the first cell of Result Column (Column C of Excel). Drag and get the required result.

Hide Helper Column.

**Note:** Array Data starts from cell B2

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If the first array is B1:K1 the second might be created with:

```
=IF(B1=6,COLUMN()-SUM(A2:$B2)-1,"")
```

in B2 and copied across to suit.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is iterate over the array and count the spaces by accumulating into a collector variable. You can find the code below it just pops into and alert window.(Javascript)

```js
var array = [1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 6, 6, 2, 4]
var resultArray = []
var i = 0;
var distance = 0;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  distance++;
  if (array[i] == 6) {
    resultArray.push(distance);
    distance = 0;
  }
}

alert(resultArray);
```

I took an attempt at doing in excel.

You can place a command button and define a sub function like below and you will get the results expected. For instructions on how to place a command button http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html#command-button

```
Sub DistanceOf6InString(x As String)
Size = Len(x)
distance = 0
result = ""
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Size
    distance = distance + 1
    If (Mid(x, i, 1) = "6") Then
        result = result & distance
        distance = 0
    End If
Next i

MsgBox result

End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
DistanceOf6InString ("1246126624")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
var rollsUntil6 = function(rolls) {
  return rolls.reduce(function(indices, roll, idx) {
    if (roll == 6) {indices.push(idx);} return indices;
  }, [-1]).map(function(val, idx, arr) {
    return val - arr[idx - 1];
  }).slice(1);
};

rollsUntil6([1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 6, 6, 2, 4]); //=> [4, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly find the array.indexOf(6,lastmatch)

var array= [1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 6, 6, 2, 4];

```
var resultArray= [], i, incr= 0;

while((i= array.indexOf(6, incr))!= -1){
    i+= 1;
    resultArray.push(i-incr);
    incr= i;
}
```

resultArray  returned value: (Array) [4,3,1]